# Ldap Group filter query to excluse nested group in member list

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I want to write the `ldap` group filter where I want to pull all the `groups` and their `members` but exclude `nested group member` within specified `OU`.
It will remove the chance of cyclic group.

For example Group A contains following member:

1. user 1
2. user 2
3. Group 1

In the query I only want Group A with user 1 and user 2.

The filter example is `(&(objectClass=Group)(member=*))`  but I do not know what are the options I can use in the member filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the members of a certain group you would use a filter like `(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=rdn-of-the-very-group))` and include `member`in the list of attributes to retrieve.  Without further assistance by an extended search control you only will get direct members, so no worries about members of nested groups.  In order to eliminate nested groups from the search result, include `objectClass`in the attribute list.  You'll have to filter on the client side, though.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion . I am using IDM  tool where we are fetching records from AD. As per my requirement we need to fetch all the group and member of those group (excluding group as member). I have only option to put the filter criteria in ldap search filter. I can not provide individual group name in filter condition. Is there any way to write generic filter criteria ?

Comment: So, why don't you just use `(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=*))`?